# Converting partition to primary

Tags: partitioning

Here is the scenario. I have windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10, dual boot, on an SSD:

```
Disk 1:
    C:(NTFS) 50GB - Primary partition
    Other (EXT4) 51 GB - Logical partition
    Unallocated space 11 GB
```

I am trying to extend the `EXT4` partition with the unallocated space but no tools that I have tried will let me. I assume (please correct if wrong) that it is because it is a logical partition.

My question is really 2:

- Will changing the partition to primary allow me to extend it?
- Would changing the partition to primary break the Ubuntu installation?

Ubuntu is my main OS on this box so would love to not break it!

**UPDATE:** More info

[image: gparted]

From the above image I can see that the unallocated space is outside of the primary partition so I cannot extend my logical partition using that.

Am I right in assuming that I can't extend my primary partition (`/dev/sda2`) as it is currently mounted and that I will have to boot into gparted in order to achieve what I need?

Comment: No and yes, definitely. If you have a logical partition - any logical partition - that partition, alone or along others, must be inside one primary partition.  First extend the primary partition *then* extend the logical partition inside. GParted does the job perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelBay Thank you for taking the time to comment. I have updated my question

Comment: Yes, you can't manage partition that are in use. You must boot a live session for that.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to extend the EXT4 partition with the unallocated space but no tools that I have tried will let me.

That's because

1. You need to use the proper tool, e.g. GParted from a LiveCD, while none of the filesystems on the SSD are mounted.
2. The logical partition (/dev/sda5) cannot be extended until the extended partition (/dev/sda2) is first extended into the unallocated region.
   This would be more obvious if you posted the entire graphical representation of the SSD.

The logical partition (represented by the block box) currently fully occupies the extended partition (represented by the cyan box), so the logical partition cannot be made larger; there is no unused space within the extended partition.

If you extend the extended partition (/dev/sda2) first, then you will be able to extend the logical partition (/dev/sda5).

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no way. use livecd `acronic disk director` or any linux (with `gparted`)
2. what for? Why change to primary? Expand and let it be logical.